# SyntaxError (amazon-sagemaker-object-has-no-attribute)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running the code cell below, on SageMaker Notebook instance.

```
pd.concat([train_data['y_yes'], train_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1)], axis=1).to_csv('train.csv', index=False, header=False)
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train/train.csv')).upload_file('train.csv')
s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
```

And if I hit, the following error is appearing:

```
AttributeError: 'SageMaker' object has no attribute 's3_input'
```

Comment: How was the sagemaker object initialized?

Comment: I was building an Amazon SageMaker pre-built XGBoost model, and reformat the header and first column of the training data and load the data from the S3 bucket.

Comment: See the link : https://aws.amazon.com/id/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 15):

```
s3_input_train = sagemaker.input.TrainingInput(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
```

did not work for me, but

```
s3_input_train = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
```

did.

Instead of input, use `sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(parameters)`

Answer (score 4):

As per the official [github code](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/e774fcf37e943bb91f9c2668019f20f0f325c6da/src/sagemaker/inputs.py#L83-L85), s3_input function was planned to be updated to TrainingInput. The documentation for the tutorial might not be updated for this change. Please try using [TrainingInput](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/inputs.html) function instead.

Replace the line: `s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')`

with:

```
s3_input_train = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
```

Comment: How the syntax is? I am new to develop phyton libraries

Comment: @OktaIhzaGifari Adding the syntax.

Comment: @OktaIhzaGifari, answer was updated. Please let me know if it solved your problem?

Comment: Update the answer from to  `sagemaker.input.TrainingInput` to `sagemaker.TrainingInput`